# How to share Title and description from android to facebook using facebook sdk 4.1.2

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook sdk 4.1.2 to share contents to Facebook .
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android
This is the link i reffered for doing this task And was successfull in sharing a link content in facebook.

```
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(ShareActivity.this);
              ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://ramees.com/Uploads/VideoGallery/17_VG/1_Video_Gallery.mp4"))
                .build();
            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

I have used the above code to post a link content in facebook and it is working successfully.But i didn't find any code to post title and description only without any link content or image. Can anyone help to know how can i do this with Facebook sdk 4.1.2 itself.

Comment: Are you trying to just post a simple status update to a Facebook account on behalf of your application?

Comment: It is not just posting a status.It is just like posting an article without image or video ,means Just Title and description

Comment: @Ramees : Have you found any solution?We are facing same issue.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(ShareActivity.this);
            ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("og:type", "books.book")
                    .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
                    .putString("og:description","In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
                    .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3").build();

            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType("books.reads").putObject("book", object)
                    .build();
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
            shareDialog.show(content);

        }
```

Comment: Why are we using "og:type", books.book for??